# How should be EJB Stateless Session Bean correctly injected into the web module?

Tags: java, netbeans, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, ejb-3.1

Being completely new to Java EE (but not to Java itself) I'm trying to build a very simple "Enterprise Application" with Hibernate as JPA provider and JSF as the actual UI framework. For this purposes I'm using the NetBeans 7 with GlassFish 3.1.

**{ApplicationName}-ejb:**

I've accomplished to generate **entity classes** from database and **local sesssion beans** for these entities. **Beans.xml** is in place.

```
@Stateless
public class QuestFacade extends AbstractFacade<Quest> implements QuestFacadeLocal {
    // some methods here as well as EntityManager injection ...
}
```

**{ApplicationName}-war:**

I've created a simple POJO as a backing bean for the JSF page. I've annotated it with `javax.inject.@Named` and `javax.enterprise.context.@SessionScoped`. This backing bean is now accessible from the JSF page as well as being injected when the actual page is accessed. **Beans.xml** is in place as well.

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class QuestBean implements Serializable {

    @EJB
    protected QuestFacade questFacade;

    // several methods delegating lookups to the questFacade ...
}
```

Having this deployed and page accessed, I'm, however, getting an error from GlassFish that the `QuestFacade` cannot be looked up by the JNDI.

The stacktrace is quite long but the initial cause could be enough:

```
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'model.session.QuestFacade#model.session.QuestFacade' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: model.session.QuestFacade#model.session.QuestFacade not found]
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:518)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:455)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.resolveEjbReference(EjbNamingReferenceManagerImpl.java:173)
    ... 74 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: model.session.QuestFacade#model.session.QuestFacade not found
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.doLookup(TransientContext.java:248)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.lookup(TransientContext.java:215)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(SerialContextProviderImpl.java:77)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.lookup(LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.java:119)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:505)
    ... 78 more
```

I understand that I'm persuading GlassFish to inject an EJB from a different module within the same application. Should the `@Remote` interface be used instead? I've also tried to explicitely specify the name for both `@Stateless` and `@EJB` annotation but without any success.

I believe that I'm doing something fundamentaly wrong, but I cannot find out what.

Any suggestion or would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I believe that I'm doing something fundamentaly wrong, but I cannot find out what.

What you're doing wrong is that if you implement a business interface (either `@Local` or `@Remote`), then you must declare the variable where injection takes place as having the type of that interface, not of the actual bean class.

So in your case:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class QuestBean implements Serializable {

    @EJB
    protected QuestFacadeLocal questFacade;

    // several methods delegating lookups to the questFacade ...
}
```

However, a business interface is not required in EJB when you're doing local (in-jvm) communication. As you discovered, if you don't specify a business interface at all for your EJB, you can inject the bean class itself. This is because you then automatically get the so-called `no-interface view`.

If you want, you can optionally declare that you want BOTH the local view and the no-interface view. In that way, you can inject your bean class in places whether either the bean type itself is declared or its business interface. For this you use the `@LocalBean`.

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class QuestFacade extends AbstractFacade<Quest> implements QuestFacadeLocal {
    // some methods here as well as EntityManager injection ...
}
```

Injection can thus happen in two ways now:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class QuestBean implements Serializable {

    @EJB
    protected QuestFacadeLocal questFacade; // possible because of local view
    @EJB
    protected QuestFacade questFacadeN; // possible because of no-interface view

    // several methods delegating lookups to the questFacade ...
}
```

In practice I didn't found much use for having both methods available at the same time though, but maybe this adds to your understanding.

Comment: Though I managed to help myself, as I pointed out in my answer, I consider your answer to be better for it provides an explanation whereare my doesn't. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the problem was that I generated `@Local` session beans. Per [this tutorial](http://netbeans.dzone.com/articles/develop-java-ee-6-app-jsf2?page=0,3) it is no longer necessary (?) to specify the `@Local` or `@Remote` interface. I still not completely understand the problem though.

I Hope this answer could potentialy save up some time to somebody :-)

Jarda